# Как разрешить вводить только цифры/буквы с if elif else

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
name = input("Введи свое имя: ")
age = input("Укажите свой возраст: ")
```

Я хочу что-бы в 1 варианте нельзя было вводить цифры, а во втором буквы. Как это сделать с if elif else ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все пояснения в коде:

```
import re


age = ''
name = '' # Можно убрать

name = input("Введи свое имя: ")
print()

while (not age.isdigit()): # Цикл работает до тех пор, пока isdigit() не определит, что переменная age имеет в себе только цифры десятичной системы.
    age = input("Укажите свой возраст: ")
    print()
    if (not age.isdigit()): # Данный оператор ветвления служит только для сообщения пользователю.
        print('Возраст необходимо указать цифрами!')
    else:
        print("Отлично! Вы догадались ввести свой возраст цифрами.")          

age = int(age) # т.к. Условие цикла While пролезло дальше, мы спокойно можем преобразовать age в int (Всегда, всегда input - это str)

name = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]+|[\d]+', r'', name).strip() # Есть и другие варианты ограничить ввод цифр в переменную name, но этот вариант решается в одну строку. 
                                                    # Операции с регулярными выражениями, по сути убирает все спец.символы (-=+\/|":"/?.#@ и тд. ) заменяя их на пустую строку.
                                                    # А так же убирает цифры и пробелы с краев
                                                    # Не забудьте импортировать/ ' import re '
                                                    # подробнее тут: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html
print()
print("Тип переменной name: ", type(name))
print("Тип переменной age: ", type(age)) # Теперь с Age можно работать математически.
print()
print('#' * 80)
print("Ваше имя: ", name)
print("Указанный возраст: ", age)
print('#' * 80)
```

Answer (score 4):

Можно так

```
def main():
    name = input("Введи свое имя: ")
    for i in name:
        if i.isdigit():
            raise ValueError("Имя не должно содержать цифр!")
    age = input("Укажите свой возраст: ")
    
    for i in age:
        if i.isdigit() is not True:
            raise ValueError("Возраст должен быть из цифр!")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Александр тогда ваша программа должна ведь упасть после ексепшена, наверное это все в try - except обернуть?

Comment: Да конечно , нужно в try-except и while True.

Comment: А что если захочет зарегистрироваться сын Илона Маска? =)

Comment: Программа вежливо его зарегистрирует)

Answer (score 1):

Так, доработал ответ Александра:

```
def main():

    flag_name = True
    while flag_name:
        flag_name = False
        name = input("Введи свое имя: ")
        try:
            for i in name:
                if i.isdigit():
                    raise ValueError("Имя не должно содержать цифр!")
        except Exception:
            print("Имя не должно содержать цифр!")
            flag_name = True

    flag_age = True
    while flag_age:
        flag_age=False
        age = input("Укажите свой возраст: ")
        try:
            for i in age:
                if i.isdigit() is not True:
                    raise ValueError("Возраст должен быть из цифр!")
        except Exception:
            print("Возраст должен быть из цифр!")
            flag_age=True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Out:

```
(D:\user_win_home\code\python_new3\test_keras_gensim\envs) D:\user_win_home\code\python_new3\help_stud_so>python app.py
Введи свое имя: ko 123
Имя не должно содержать цифр!
Введи свое имя: kons
Укажите свой возраст: wer
Возраст должен быть из цифр!
Укажите свой возраст: rtyt
Возраст должен быть из цифр!
Укажите свой возраст: 123
```